# Editing text file using awk/sed

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file where i would like to copy a matched pattern to the  next two lines below the line containing the matched pattern.The pattern is not fixed.For example

```
  1.  m_cg 
  2.  do0
  3.  do1
  4.  a_cg  
  5.  do2
  6.  do3
```

I want the output as

```
  1.m_cg
  2.m_cg do0
  3.m_cg do1
  4.a_cg
  5.a_cg do2
  6.a_cg do3
```

.*_cg is the pattern match .Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this awk one-liner should do:

```
awk '/_cg$/{p=$0;print;next}{print p,$0}' file
```

with your example:

```
kent$  cat f
m_cg
do0
do1
a_cg
do2
do3

kent$  awk '/_cg$/{p=$0;print;next}{print p,$0}' f
m_cg
m_cg do0
m_cg do1
a_cg
a_cg do2
a_cg do3
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/\s//g;/_cg/{h;b};G;s/\.(.*)\n.*(\..*)$/\2 \1/' file
```

Remove all whitespace. On encountering a line containing `_cg` copy it to the hold space (HS) and then print it out. For all other lines, append the copied line (HS) and rearrange the line to suit the required format.